# Implementing a Search Text Box in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, textfield

Would someone be able to help with the following in swift:

- I have created a textfield. When I click on the textfield it displays    a table with a list

  - I have created a func that searches through the array and any matches will be added to the filtered array but how then do i add this to my table
    -Also is there a way that when i now select a new value from the table it populates into my textfield?

I'm basically trying to create a dropdown

This is my code

```
import UIKit

var names = ["frank", "john", "harry", "mike", "jones"]
var filtered:[String] = []

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var searchActive : Bool = false
    @IBOutlet weak var searchText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var personTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        personTable.alpha = 0
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func searchTextClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        if(personTable.alpha == 0){
            personTable.alpha = 1
            searchActive = true;
            searchText(searchText, textDidChange: "")

        }else{
            personTable.alpha = 0
            searchActive = false;
        }
    }

    func tableView(personTable: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return names.count;
    }


    func tableView(personTable: UITableView!,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func searchText(searchText: UITextField, textDidChange newSearch: String) {

       let filteredArr = names.filter{$0.containsCharacters(searchText.text)}
    self.personTable.reloadData()
    }


}

extension String {
    func containsCharacters(ch:String)-> Bool{

        var err:NSError?

        let reg = NSRegularExpression(pattern: ch, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &err)

        if let matches = reg?.matchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions.WithoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0,count(self))) where matches.count != 0 {

            return true

        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

For good reasons drop down's does not exist in iOS.
You should use a UIPickerView or add add a search field to your tableview.
In the latter example you should implement the UISearchBarDelegate
and use one of it's delegate methods to do you actions. Could look something like this

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "" {
        self.filteredDkStationsKeys = self.allDkStationsKeys
    }else{
        self.filteredDkStationsKeys.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.filteredDkStationsKeys =  self.allDkStationsKeys.filter { (  $0.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(searchText.lowercaseString) )  }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Where you can replace the filter stuff with your own filter functions (I show the filteredDkStations in the table). This would give you a table which is getting smaller and smaller as less and less text matches the search input. It looks great!

Comment: sorry @user1700737 but I'm not sure what you are asking, how do i integrate this into my code?

Comment: your tableview class must extend UISearchBarDelegate like this: class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{ .....} Then you can implement the delegate functions such as the "searchable(....){....} But here is a very nice tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift